# context free grammar tree as a feature

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to use the output of StanfordParser as a feature for my models?
The output of StanfordParser looks like this:
Sentence: 'hello how are you?'

```
Result - [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SBARQ', [Tree('WHADVP', [Tree('RB', ['hello']), Tree('WRB', ['how'])]), Tree('SQ', [Tree('VBP', ['are']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP', ['you'])])]), Tree('.', ['?'])])])]

Result[0] - (ROOT (SBARQ
(WHADVP (RB hello) (WRB how))
(SQ (VBP are) (NP (PRP you)))
(. ?)))
```

Comment: If this relates to some particular machine learning library, you should mention it and add a tag.

Comment: What NLP model are you using / planning to use? Applicability of this data depends on model's type.

Comment: I plan to use Logistic Regression on the output of Stanford Parser